# Can't get SSH ProxyCommand with sudo on proxy machine to work

Tags: ssh, proxy

I was trying to configure my SSH configs for easier workflows, but I've run against a wall here.
I have a jump host which requires `sudo ssh` to get to all the other machines.

I've figured out that if I run `ssh -tt jumphost sudo ssh desthost` that I get asked for my `sudo` password and I get access to `desthost`

Now, when I add `ProxyCommand ssh -tt jumphost sudo ssh %h` to my `ssh_config` and run `ssh desthost` then I just get a blank connection.

Debug printout:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/deiga/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/deiga/.ssh/config line 34: Applying options for desthost
debug1: /Users/deiga/.ssh/config line 167: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/tmp/ssh-deiga@desthost:22" does not exist
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -tt jumphost sudo ssh desthost
debug1: identity file /Users/deiga/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/deiga/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/deiga/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/deiga/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: [sudo] password for deiga:

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: Sorry, try again.

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: [sudo] password for deiga:

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how the proxy command work. Basic example how you should do jumphosts is this way:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost
```

which doesn't support running sudo on remote machine. But you can do the same with netcat command:

```
ProxyCommand ssh jumphost nc %h %p
```

And to make it working with your `sudo` requirement, just add the `sudo` command:

```
ProxyCommand ssh jumphost sudo nc %h %p
```

If it will not help, please try to diagnose the problem with verbose logs from ssh (`-vvv`).

Comment: I've tried all those. But the jumphost requires a tty to sudo and it requires sudo to connect to the desthost. So if I do `ProxyCommand ssh -tt jumphost sudo nc %h %p ` my ssh connection just hangs without asking for password or anything